# knockout.js nested foreach on nested array

Tags: mvvm, foreach, durandal, nested-loops, knockout-2.0

I've been looking at examples of nested `foreach` loops in `knockout` all afternoon, and I haven't been able to get anything working. My current setup, at least the relevant parts, are below.

**ViewModel:**

```
var sample = {
    this.pageData = ko.observable();
    this.panels = ko.observableArray();
};

ko.utils.extend(sample.prototype, {
    activate: { 

        this.pageData(sampleData);
        this.panels([
            {
        name: 'column1',
        keys: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
        loadedWidgets: ko.observableArray()
            },
            {
                name: 'column2',
                keys: ['key4', 'key5'],
                loadedWidgets: ko.observableArray()
            },
            {
                name: 'column3',
                keys: ['key6'],
                loadedWidgets: ko.observableArray()
            }
        ]);

        this.loadWidgetPanels(this.panels(), this.pageData());

    },
    loadWidgetPanels: function (panels, pageData) {
            for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
                    var screens = filterContentByKey(pageData.Content, panels[i].keys);
                    if (screens) {
                        panels[i].loadedWidgets.push(widgetFactory.getWidgets(screens));
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div>
    <!-- ko foreach: panels -->
        <div class="3columnStyle">
            <!-- ko foreach: loadedWidgets -->
                <!--ko compose: $data --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I've confirmed that I'm getting back the right data in the right format in my `loadedWidgets`, but they don't display in the view. I can tell that the view at least knows how much data is there, because my DOM has a `ko compose` element for each widget. For example, the first column has a handful of widgets, and that div gets created with a handful of widgets in it. Column 2 has 2 widgets, and it gets 2 `compose` elements. Column 3 has 1 widget and gets one element. It's just not displaying the widgets themselves. Do I need additional elements or additional binding somewhere?

I have a working model of this that doesn't rely on nested loops. Instead of using the array of objects, it just creates each of the observable arrays. In other words, it's not looping. Instead of one array containing three objects, each with its own array, I have three arrays:

```
this.column1Widgets();
this.column2Widgets();
this.column3Widgets();
```

They're constructed the same way, just manually instead of looping. And the View looks more like this:

```
<div class="3columnStyle">
    <!-- ko foreach: column3Widgets -->
        <!-- ko compose: $data --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<div class="3columnStyle">
    <!-- ko foreach: column3Widgets -->
        <!-- ko compose: $data --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<div class="3columnStyle">
    <!-- ko foreach: column3Widgets -->
        <!-- ko compose: $data --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I'm not sure why it's not working with the nested loop, but since the data is identical, I'm sure there's something I'm missing in setting up the View.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle, jsbin or plunker which shows your issue? That would make it a lot easier to assist you.

Comment: Have you tried using non-containerless bindings (i.e. putting the `foreach` binding into a div)? I'd do that, and then use the knockout context debugger for chrome to see if there's something funny going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eric Taylor suggested, it must have something to do with the containerless binding. I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmoore82/54GSf/) with some oversimplified object models, but changing my DOM from the above to the following immediately fixed the issue:

```
<div>Test</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: panels">
<ul data-bind="foreach: loadedWidgets">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I don't think I have a good grasp of how the containers interact with the binding yet.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's difficult to tell for sure.  I'm a little suspicious of the `sample` object in your viewmodel.  But it seems to me that you're not actually nesting your `foreach`'s.

In your view, replace

```
foreach: loadedWidgets
```

with

```
foreach: $data.loadedWidgets
```

You need to reference the parent `foreach` in some way.  $data represents the current item in the parent `foreach`, and that item, if I understand your model correctly, contains a `loadedWidgets` key.

Also, there's no need for containerless binding in your case.

Comment: Apparently it's not a problem with the nesting. It's the containerless binding. The nesting works as I had it, but the tip about the containerless binding led me to the answer. Just need to figure out the best way to do this with my actual DOM. Thanks!